# Sending an XML file contains gpg signature with PHP+cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, gnupg

I have an xml file and a GPG signature is in it, in `<SIGNATURE>` tag.

Here is the xml:

```
$xml = "<DATA>
 ....
  <SIGNATURE>-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.5 (GNU/Linux)

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
  </SIGNATURE>
</DATA>";
```

When I send this xml with perl, the respond is ok and remote host accepts the signature.

But if I send this xml with php and cURL, remote server will dismiss the signature.

The next modules are used in perl script: `use URI (); use GnuPG qw( :algo ); use LWP::UserAgent (); use IO::Socket::SSL;`

Next cURL options are set in the php script:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
```

I guess there is problem with curl ....Probably a curl setting is missed, but I don't know which. I have tried `urlencode`, `qoutemeta` php functions for `$xml` string, but no results.

Comment: I have tried with send xml with fsockopen method, but result is just the same: remote server dismisses signature, so it is not cURL problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add user agent option.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070206 Firefox/3.0.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);